# Using SELECT CONCAT in MySQL returns the CONCAT command as well in Bash

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

This is the SQL statement:

```
mysql -u user -p password -e  "SELECT concat(name,'-',number) from users 
where email='test@test.com'"

Expected output: john-1234

Actual output: concat(name,'-',number)
               john-1234
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: That's the column name. Try `... concat(name,'-',number) as XYZ ...` and see what happens.

Comment: I'm using this command in bash and it's extra work to split the output. Is there a way that I can only return the result?

Comment: @Cid You're right. Got the answer I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will return column names. You can give it a more useful alias like this:

```
SELECT concat(name,'-',number) as username from users 
where email='test@test.com'
```

EDIT: Looks like @jarlh beat me to it in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

just give an alias of your column name other wise it will concat(name,'-',number) as column name

```
"SELECT concat(name,'-',number) as output from users 
where email='test@test.com'"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is name of the column.

You can name it in other way:

```
SELECT concat(name,'-',number) AS nameAndNumber from users where email='test@test.com'
```